# Matlab Matrix Syntax

Tags: matlab, syntax, matrix

I have a Matlab Code Snippet and I try to write in C++, but I really don't understand
what is happening there:

```
for c = 1:3
    Id = double(I(:,:,c))/255;
    Wc(:,:,c) = sum(Id(pixels).*weights, 3);
end
```

There is an image I of size 480x640x3. In the first Iteration the first channel of the image is
saved in Id, which then has a size of 480x640. But what is happening in the next line? I just don't
understand that syntax.

pixels and weights are of size 300x383x4x1.

So what does this line exactly do?:

```
sum(Id(pixels).*weights, 3);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum(X, n)` summarizes all elements of a matrix `X` across the *n*-th dimension, so this:

```
sum(Id(pixels) .* weights, 3);
```

really does the following:

- Extracts a sub-matrix from matrix `Id`, `pixels` being the indices of the extracted values: 
  matrix `Id` is imlicitly converted to a column vector, and the resulting sub-matrix is of the same size as `pixels` (each value being equal to `Id(p)`, where `p` is the corresponding element in `pixels`).
- Multiplies the extracted matrix by another matrix `weights` element-by-element (note that the multiplication operator is `.*`)
- Summarizes all elements of the resulting 3-D matrix along the third dimension.

You can look into [the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) for more information.

#### EDIT: A Simple Example

Let's assume that:

```
Id = [10 20; 30 40; 50 60; 70 80];
pixels(:, :, 1) = [4 4; 4 4];
pixels(:, :, 2) = [6 6; 6 6];
pixels(:, :, 3) = [8 8; 8 8];
```

that is, `Id` is a **2-D** matrix, and `pixels` is **3-D**. Now, `Id(pixels)` would yield:

```
ans(:, :, 1) =

  70  70
  70  70

ans(:, :, 2) =

  40  40
  40  40

ans(:, :, 3) =

  80  80
  80  80
```

because if you convert `Id` to a column vector (try `Id(:)`), `70` is the 4<sup>th</sup> element, `40` is the 6<sup>th</sup>, and `80` is the 8<sup>th</sup>. Note that the result has the same dimensions as `pixels` (not `Id`!).

Hope that helps!

Comment: thx for your quick response. Actually I have problems with the dimensions. I just don't understand what's the result of Id(pixels), because they are of different sizes 2D(4D)

Comment: Okay, I've elaborated on that. Please see the updated answer. If you need a simple example to further explain that, let me know.

Comment: A simple example would be great :)

Comment: Ok I think I've got it. An example would be nice anyway. Thx, you helped me a lot.

Comment: There you go. Glad to help :)